# Stop Visual Studio from breaking on unhandled javascript errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, exception

### The Issue

In Visual Studio 2015 I have some old code that is a Web project.  I just need to make a small change but I can't test in debug mode.  I constantly have to test all changes after publishing due to the simple fact that I can NOT stop VS from breaking on JavaScript errors!

Specifically I have the following continue to pop on on me...
[image]

I have tried every type of configuration I can think of in the `Exception Settings` window.  I also currently have `Just My Code` enabled/checked.

Anyone have any idea why VS will not let me stop these annoying messages?  The code runs fine with this small error and I don't want to fix anything more than I have to (there are a lot of those issues in the page).

---

### UPDATE #1

As suggested I also have tried disabling the `Script` option found in the `Just-In-Time` settings...
[image]

This did not seem to work either.  Same thing happens still.

Answer (score 0):

What code are you trying to debug? I'm not sure if you are trying to debug C# or another language other than Javascript. 
Visual Studio does allow you to turn off debugging for Javascript though.

In Visual Studio, go to `Tools\Options\Debugging\Just in time\Script` and uncheck `Script.`

Comment: Sorry I added a new tag.  I spaced on that.  It's a `Web` project (ASP.Net).  SCRIPT!  Ahh I missed that checking now...

Comment: Updated question per your answer suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey Arvo, sorry you are having this issue man. Maybe try to disable script debugging in your Internet Options dialog box? Either that or enable or disable Just-In-Time debugging. Maybe one of these options could help you.  [Check out this link for more info...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I had no success. I have tried to uncheck all the options under `Just-In-Time`. I guess that's how I would "disable" it. Is there somewhere else I can disable it at a lower level. If that is the only place then it looks like I'm still stuck where I was. Interesting enough, when I made some changes on my IIS config (to allow parent paths) for debugging. I ended up testing for this error again because of your message. It gave me the error in IE instead of the VS IDE! I closed IE and debugged again but it reverted back to throwing an error in the VS IDE.